# Failover support for activemq REST api

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using activemq using a custom message servlet through REST api.
For message retrieval url typically looks like 
"http://localhost:8161/MessageServlet/MessageServlet?destination=queue://test.queue&clientId=Tester".

I am trying incorporate failover mechanism using pure master slave mode("http://activemq.apache.org/pure-master-slave.html").

I have already configured my master slave and it is running using jms connection.

My question is, what should be my failover url look like when i am uisng REST api.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arijit

Comment: Hi, Arijit, Please look on this question. I am keep searching but not getting any start. Please hlp!!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the REST client perspective, you'll need to abstract the requests (proxy URL) or handle the failover of the client connection using 3rd party libraries (see [HttpClient failover support](https://github.com/exalead/commons-httpclient-failover), etc.)

If you go with the abstraction approach, then consider doing one of the following to proxy the requests to AMQ and provide failover support...

- can you use Camel [load balancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) which supports endpoint failover support
- use a 3rd party load balancer (Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html), [perlba](http://www.danga.com/perlbal/)l, etc)