# How to enable the activemq Rest Api to support a Master/Slave configuration using a shared storage

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have set up activeMQ as a master/slave configuration using shared storage for enabling high availability of data. My application consumes messages from activemq using ActveMQ's REST API. How can I configure my system such that these REST API calls will also adhere to the master/slave failover strategy.
One solution mentioned at the below link is to use a third party load balancer.

[Failover support for activemq REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663342/failover-support-for-activemq-rest-api)

But I would prefer to explore any configuration options available before making use of a load balancer.

A workaround I could find was to

1. Copy and deploy the API web application and the libraries  from ActiveMQ's embedded jetty server and deploy it as a WAR on an independent JETTY server.
2. Modify the web.xml of the API web application to pass the failover URL as a context parameter **org.apache.activemq.brokerURL**
3. My application now communicates with this jetty server which would in turn route the requests to ActiveMQ.

The reason why I copied the API web application to a seperate server was because the embedded Jetty server was giving preference to its own broker over the servlet context parameter.

Is there some configuration for ensuring that the failover URL gets picked by the embedded jetty server or is there a better approach for handling the Rest calls with failover support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seem reasonable as long as you run two copies of the jetty server, to not create a single point of failure.

Actually, you can still use the AMQ embedded jetty but simply alter the application deployed. That way, you would have two servers. That requires a load balancer in front of them as well, but that is always the case for high available web solutions.